How to resize rendered object to match window size in R Shiny?
In running the below MWE R Shiny code the sidebar panel width correctly remains fixed while the main panel expands as the user expands the size of the window. When the user increases the window size, the size of the plot also increases which is correct. However, when the user decreases the size of the window after having increased it, the plot size does not readjust to the smaller window size: the plot size remains the same large size it was when the window size was increased. How can the plot size be readjusted when the user reduces the window size? While maintaining the same fixed-width sidebar panel.
This automatic resizing works fine when using the standard sidebarPanel() and mainPanel() functions of Shiny, but I wasn't able to fix the size of the sidebar panel width using these standard functions. The below MWE code correctly fixes the sidebar panel width.
MWE code:
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title goes here"),
  div(
    style = "display: flex; align-items: flex-start;",
    div(
      class = "sidebar",
      style = "flex-shrink: 0; max-width: 280px; min-width: 280px;",
      wellPanel(
        h2("Sidebar Panel"),
        selectInput("species", "Select Species:", 
                    choices = c("All", unique(as.character(iris$Species))),
                    selected = "All")
      )
    ),
    div(
      class = "main-panel",
      style = "flex-grow: 1; margin-left: 20px;",  # main panel left margin
      h2("Main Panel"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data <- if (input$species == "All") {
      iris
    } else {
      subset(iris, Species == input$species)
    }
    
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = "Sepal Length vs Sepal Width",
           x = "Sepal Length",
           y = "Sepal Width")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. I just ran your code, and it looks okay. Are you trying to reduce the size of the main panel display?

Hi. When the user expands the size of the window, the plot width correctly stretches out to fit the resized window. But when I go to reduce the window size (after having increased it), the plot width doesn't shrink back down to the size of the window. That's the issue I'm trying to address, the failure of the plot to shrink back down. Note that the plot resizing works fine using sidebarPanel and mainPanel but I'm trying to stick with CSS div() because it allows me to fix the width of the siderbar panel.

Here is the solution to the problem:
div(
      class = "main-panel",
      style = "flex-grow: 1; margin-left: 20px;resize:both;overflow:auto;",  # main panel left margin
      h2("Main Panel"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )

In the CSS of the main panel div(), I added resize:both; and overflow:auto; to automatically resize your plot when the window is both maximized and minimized. I hope it helps!
